# How to restrict access to a page or folder in a SharePoint site with anonymous access?

Tags: 2010, permissions, publishing-page, anonymous-authentication, access

I would like to restrict access to specific parts of my SharePoint site that has anonymous access enabled. For example, everyone can access the entire site, but I want a page to only be accessible to certain individuals as specified in the permissions of the page. What is the best way to get this accomplished?

Comment: Break the inheritance and remove everybody and then add the required users

Comment: I already have, but the problem is that anyone with access to our intranet can view our site (anonymous access). I only want those specified to be able to go to this certain page within the site; blocked for everyone else.